# With CSS, Position a div (B) below (vertically, not z-index) another div (A) based on div A's height and position

Tags: html, css

Consider the following jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/0fwhmhLe/

html markup:

```
<div class="city-losangeles-bg">

            <div class="user-container user-container-losangeles">

                <div class="user-pic user-pic-losangeles"></div>

                <div class="user-name-container">
                    <p class="user-name">User Name</p>
                    <div class="user-name-mask"></div>
                </div>

                <hr class="underline">

                <div class="ellipse-container">
                    <div class="ellipse ellipse-losangeles-1"></div>
                    <div class="ellipse ellipse-losangeles-2 ellipse-with-left-margin"></div>
                    <div class="ellipse ellipse-losangeles-3 ellipse-with-left-margin"></div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <p class="user-text user-text-losangeles">Some text that needs to be below the user-container div, based on the position and height of user-container</p>

</div>
```

css:

```
.city-losangeles-bg
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 1230px;
    top: 0px;
    background-color: orange;
    position: relative;
}

.user-container
{
    position: relative;
    width: 206px;
    height: 192px;
  background-color: green;
}
.user-container-losangeles
{
    left: 41%;
    top: 25px;
}

.user-pic
{
    position: relative;
    width: 73px;
    height: 73px;
    left: -36.5px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
}

.user-pic-losangeles
{
    background-color: red;
}

.user-name-mask
{
    position: relative;
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
  top: 0;
}
.user-name
{
    position: relative;
    font-family: Ariel;
    font-size: 28px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    /*top: -6px;*/ /*so text hides properly under color bar reveal animation */
}

.underline
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 178px;
    top: 138px;
    left: 14px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.ellipse-container
{
    position: absolute;
    width: 126px;
    height: 30px;
    top: 162px;
    left: 40px;
}
.ellipse
{
    position: relative;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    float: left;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
}

.ellipse-with-left-margin
{
    margin-left: 18px;
}

.ellipse-losangeles-1
{
    background-color: #4574b4;
}
.ellipse-losangeles-2
{
    background-color: #71c8ca;
}
.ellipse-losangeles-3
{
    background-color: #e6dddd;
}

.user-text
{
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 0; /* 100 */

    font-family: Ariel;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #848484;
}

.user-text-losangeles
{
    margin-left: 29%;
    width: 50%;
}
```

I can't figure out how to make the paragraph tag **user-text user-text-losangeles** always be below the div user-container **user-container-losangeles**.  I thought they should automatically stack and if I changed **user-container-losangeles**'s top property that **user-text-losangeles** would get bumped down as well.

Someone tell me what obvious mistake I am making please!!

Comment: This is a problem with the structure. You have two options. Positioning it using absolute and top on both components. Or grouping the two components inseide another div in order to position them toghether. (You would like also to search for use flexboxes in order to achive better responsive layouts.

Comment: Aren't user-container-losangeles and user-text-losangeles combined in a div already?  (city-losangeles-bg)

Comment: yes they are, I dind't see it. Adding a margin-top to the text or a margin-bottom to the container will do the trick.

Comment: I'm afraid that does not work @arrasco.  the idea I am going after is that when I change the css:top value of user-container-losangeles, user-text-losangeles should move down the same amount, ie always maintain the same spacing from user-container-losangeles.  This does not happen no matter what settings I have tried on either element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `padding-top: 25px;` on the container (`.city-losangeles-bg`) instead of the `top:25px;` of `.user-container-losangeles`

https://jsfiddle.net/y8pocwsn/1/

The reason: With `position:relative` and a `top`setting an element is simply moved down from its original position, but the subsequent elements are NOT moved. The space reserved for the element is still the space it would occupy with `top: 0` , which is the same as if that element would have `position: static`

Comment: Champion!  Thanks for the clear explanation as well.